# How to filter products by size in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, filtering

i'm new in react and redux.. I've been trying to filter some data of products with redux but i'm not happy with how i'm doing it. The problem is: when the page reloads the products doesnt render, only renders when i click in one of the options. Is there a good and clean way of doing it? I really appreciate any help. Thank you :)

1. Here is the product data

```
import faker from 'faker';

const PRODUCTS_DATA = [
    {
        id: 1,
        categorie: 'men',
        size: 'S',
        name: faker.commerce.productName(),
        imgUrl: 'http://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-oversized-longline-shirt-with-placement-floral-print-in-white/20232840-1-white?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain',
        price: faker.commerce.price()
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        categorie: 'men',
        size: 'M',
        name: faker.commerce.productName(),
        imgUrl: 'http://images.asos-media.com/products/calvin-klein-jeans-asos-exclusive-sweat-shorts-with-white-noise-back-pocket-logo-in-black/20558434-1-ckblack?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain',
        price: faker.commerce.price()
    },
    {
        id: 33,
        categorie: 'men',
        size: 'L',
        name: faker.commerce.productName(),
        imgUrl: 'http://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-skinny-western-denim-jacket-in-black/12887167-1-black?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain',
        price: faker.commerce.price()
    }
,
    {
        id: 34,
        categorie: 'men',
        size: 'XL',
        name: faker.commerce.productName(),
        imgUrl: 'http://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-skinny-western-denim-jacket-in-black/12887167-1-black?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain',
        price: faker.commerce.price()
    }
   
]

export default PRODUCTS_DATA;
```

2. Here is the action.js. So here i'm filtering the products size, if the size that the user chose in the option value has the same size of the products size. if yes it will return the products list with the chosen size, if not will return all products.

```
import ProductsActionTypes from './products.types';


export const filterProductsBySize = (products, size) => ({
    type: ProductsActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
    payload: {
        size: size,
        items: size === "" ? products : products.filter(product => product.size === size)
    }
});
```

3. Here is the reducer.js

```
import PRODUCTS_DATA from '../../components/Product-data';
import ProductsActionTypes from './products.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    items: PRODUCTS_DATA,
    filteredItems: []
}

const productsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ProductsActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
            return {
                ...state,
                filteredItems: action.payload.items
            }

        default:
            return state;

    }
}
export default productsReducer;
```

4. The filter component

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {filterProductsBySize} from '../../redux/products/products.actions';

const ProductFilters = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <div>
                    <label>
                        FILTER BY SIZE
                        <select
                            value={props.size}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                props.dispatch(filterProductsBySize(props.products, e.target.value))
                            }}
                        >
                            <option value="">ALL</option>
                            <option value="S">S</option>
                            <option value="M">M</option>
                            <option value="L">L</option>
                            <option value="XL">XL</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    products: state.products.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductFilters);
```

5. Here is the component where rerender the products

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Card from '../../Card';
import ProductFilters from '../../product-filters/ProductFilters';

const MensPage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Men Page</h1>
            <ProductFilters />
            <div className="row">
                {
                    props.products.filter(product => product.categorie === 'men')
                        .map(product => <Card key={product.id} product={product} />)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    products: state.products.filteredItems
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MensPage);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Product render component, you are selecting the **products.filteredItems** which is initially a null array.

The correct way -

In Action -

```
export const filterProductsBySize = (products, size) => ({
    type: ProductsActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
    payload: {
        size: size,
  }
}
```

In reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    items: PRODUCTS_DATA, 
}

case ProductsActionTypes.FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
       return state.items.filter(item => item.size === action.payload.size)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i'm having the following error in the MensPage component: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. PS: I changed the filteredItems to items in the mapState.

Comment: after following my code? Have you changed the mapStateToProps: state.products.items?

Comment: Yes sir, I changed it to items.

Comment: put a consol.log in mens page component and check if what you are getting in state.

Comment: I'm getting all the items from the console.log(props.products), but when i select any option (S, M or L) it gives me that error.

Comment: put a console.log(state) in redux function before switch

Comment: after selecting size? It should not be the case because the error tells state.items has no value.

Comment: When i select one size it gives me the error. looks like the MensPage can't get the state from the reducer.

Comment: you told you got all the products in console from MensPage. So aren't you getting products on inital render?

Comment: In the MensPage im getting all the products but when i select any size it gives me this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.`. At the same time in my react-logger i can see that the action was triggered and the reducer processed the code but for some reason the MensPage is not rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, i found a way of doing it with the use of selectors. And is working fine so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You never save size to your state and you never select size from state so in the code `<select value={props.size}` the props.size is always undefined. You could save the size in redux state and use a selector to filter products.

You should never save a copy or calculation result in redux state and since filtered products is a calculation of products you should use a selector.

Here is a working example:

```js
const {
  Provider,
  useSelector,
  connect,
} = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  items: [
    { size: 'S', id: 1 },
    { size: 'M', id: 2 },
    { size: 'L', id: 3 },
    { size: 'XL', id: 4 },
    { size: 'XL', id: 5 },
  ],
  size: '',
};
//action types
const CHANGE_SIZE = 'CHANGE_SIZE';
//action creators
const changeSize = (size) => ({
  type: CHANGE_SIZE,
  payload: size,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CHANGE_SIZE) {
    return { ...state, size: payload };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectItems = (state) => state.items;
const selectSize = (state) => state.size;
const createSelectFilteredItems = (size) =>
  createSelector(
    [selectItems, selectSize],
    (items, filterSize) =>
      size
        ? items.filter(({ size }) => size === filterSize)
        : items
  );
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const ProductFilters = ({ size, changeSize }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        FILTER BY SIZE
        <select
          value={size}
          onChange={(e) => {
            changeSize(e.target.value);
          }}
        >
          <option value="">ALL</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  size: selectSize(state),
});

const ProductFiltersContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, {
  changeSize,
})(ProductFilters);
const ProductList = () => {
  const size = useSelector(selectSize);
  const selectFilteredItems = React.useMemo(
    () => createSelectFilteredItems(size),
    [size]
  );
  const filteredProducts = useSelector(selectFilteredItems);
  return (
    <ul>
      {filteredProducts.map((p) => (
        <li key={p.id}>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(p, undefined, 2)}</pre>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ProductFiltersContainer />
    <ProductList />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

More documentation on how you can use selectors can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. But i lost myself in some parts of the code, is it possible to give an example with the code i gave you? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @mr_vmoore The action created with changeSize will set state.size and the selector createSelectFilteredItems creates a selector to get filtered `state.items`. A detailed document on how selectors can be used can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)

Comment: Thank you, You were right i had to use the a selector. After some googling and tutorials about selector i finally found a simple and less complex way of doing it and it is working fine so far. Thank you so much for showing me the way :)